# Mongorestore to a different database

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

In MongoDB, is it possible to dump a database and restore the content to a different database? For example like this:

```
mongodump --db db1 --out dumpdir
mongorestore --db db2 --dir dumpdir
```

But it doesn't work. Here's the error message:

> building a list of collections to restore from dumpdir dir
>
> don't know what to do with subdirectory "dumpdir/db1", skipping...
>
> done

Answer (score 183, accepted):

You need to actually point at the ["database name" container](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#restore-a-collection) directory "within" the output directory from the previous dump:

```
mongorestore -d db2 dumpdir/db1
```

And usually just <path> is fine as a positional argument rather than with `-dir` which would only be needed when "out of position" i.e "in the middle of the arguments list".

p.s. For archive backup file ([tested](https://github.com/namgivu/mongodb-start/blob/master/01.backup-restore.sh) with mongorestore v3.4.10)

```
mongorestore --gzip --archive=${BACKUP_FILE_GZ} --nsFrom "${DB_NAME}.*" --nsTo "${DB_NAME_RESTORE}.*"
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I think one must specify the subdirectory in the dump folder when using the `-d` option and the dump folder itself when not using `-d`. That's it.

Comment: Can you suggest solution for archived dumps( --gzip --archive) ?

Comment: @SergioRykov Seems like this is a known bug https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-1234 and will be resolved in 
3.3.10. At the moment there is no support for that.

Comment: @Philiiiiiipp Looks like this is now supported. To be honest --nsInclude  --nsExclude --nsFrom and --nsTo looks overcomplicated. I have a backup done with --archive and --gzip and I want to restore this backup in a different database. How can I do that? I think I need nsFrom and nsTo but not nsInclude and nsExclude because I don't want something to be excluded. The whole backup should be restored and only the name of the database changes.

Comment: I have tested this solution and it works, the only problem is that the DBRefs still point to the initial database entries instead of the "nsTo" database entries.

Comment: Thank you!!! Adding Docker notes
(assumes authenticated, assumes named container=my_db and new_db)
dump:
        docker exec -it my_db bash -c "mongodump --uri mongodb://db:password@localhost:27017/my_db --archive --gzip | cat > /tmp/backup.gz"
copy:
         docker cp my_db:/tmp/backup.gz local-drive\backup.gz
restore:
        docker exec -it new_db bash -c "mongorestore --uri mongodb://db:password@localhost:27017/new_db --nsFrom 'my_db.*' --nsTo 'new_db.*' --gzip --archive=/tmp/backup.gz"

Comment: The command using an archive does not work for me: I additionally had to specify `--nsInclude "${DB_NAME}.*"`, otherwise nothing gets imported. I find this bizarre, and it’s also not explicitly documented, but the example for `--nsFrom` in the official documentation also uses it.

Answer (score 21):

```
mongodump --db=DB_NAME --out=/path-to-dump
mongorestore --nsFrom "DB_NAME.*" --nsTo "NEW_DB_NAME.*" /path-to-dump
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: save my 3 hrs.
but still missing authentication process

Comment: read https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/, there are different switches for authentication like --username, --password, etc. @ZalaJanaksinh

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the answer of Blakes Seven, if your databases use authentication I got this to work using the `--uri` option, which requires a recent mongo version (>3.4.6):

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://$sourceUser:$sourcePwd@$sourceHost/$sourceDb" --gzip --archive | mongorestore --uri="mongodb://$targetUser:$targetPwd@$targetHost/$targetDb" --nsFrom="$sourceDb.*" --nsTo="$targetDb.*" --gzip --archive
```

Comment: Nowadays you also need to include `--nsInclude="$targetDb.*"` into the list of magic incantations of `mongorestore`.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you! @Blakes Seven

Adding Docker notes:
container names are interchangeable with container ID's

(assumes authenticated, assumes named container=my_db and new_db)

**dump:**

```
docker exec -it my_db bash -c "mongodump --uri mongodb://db:password@localhost:27017/my_db --archive --gzip | cat > /tmp/backup.gz"
```

**copy to workstation:**

```
docker cp my_db:/tmp/backup.gz c:\backups\backup.gz
```

**copy into new container(form backups folder):**

```
docker cp .\backup.gz new_db:/tmp
```

**restore from container tmp folder:**

```
docker exec -it new_db bash -c "mongorestore --uri mongodb://db:password@localhost:27017/new_db --nsFrom 'my_db.*' --nsTo 'new_db.*' --gzip --archive=/tmp/backup.gz"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can restore DB with another name. The syntax is:

```
mongorestore --port 27017 -u="username" -p="password" 
    --nsFrom "dbname.*" 
    --nsTo "new_dbname.*" 
    --authenticationDatabase admin /backup_path
```