# Restore mongodb dump to different db

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I've created a dump of a collection of my local mongoDB:

```
mongodump --collection myCollection --db testing --gzip
```

Now I need to restore this data to my productive server with the same collection name, but to the different db `production`:

```
mongorestore --db production /restore/dump/testing/
```

I'm not quite sure how to restore **gzip** files and if I have to select specific collections from my dump. Don't I have to specify the names of the collections or will it get the names of the files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36322080/4302328