# Problem to dump and restore mongo database

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I dump a mongo database locally like this:

```
./mongodump -h <url>:<port> -d <dbname> -u <user> -p <password> -o C:\Users\Manuel\Documents\database
```

And then I tried to restore it in another database like:

```
./mongodump -h <otherUrl>:<otherPort> -d <otherdbname> -u <otherUser> -p <otherPassword> -o C:\Users\Manuel\Documents\database
```

But I get the following:

```
finished restoring <dbname>.<oneCollection> (0 documents, 0 failures)
Failed: <dbname>.<oneCollection> : error restoring from C:\Users\Manuel\Documents\database\<dbname>\<oneCollection>.bson: this MongoDB deployment does not support retryable writes. Please add retryWrites=false to your connection string
0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I add the retryWritables, I also tried to use --uri, and then I get that authentication failed.

Comment: You need to use the `mongorestore` command to restore the dumped data. See https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/

Answer (score -1):

I feel like this is the answer that you seek: [Mongorestore to a different database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36321899/mongorestore-to-a-different-database)

You need to use `nsFrom` and `nsTo`.