# MongoDB rename DB using Compass + MONGOSH

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I'm trying to rename a db in order to create a backup, using shell from MongoDB Compass.
First I tried `db.copyDatabase("signs","signs_backup")` but I got the error message:

> MongoshDeprecatedError: [COMMON-10003] `copyDatabase()` was removed because it was deprecated in MongoDB 4.0

`db.version()` returns: '3.4.20'

Then I moved on to mongodump and mongorestore, but:

`mongodump --archive="mongo_signs1" --db=signs` returns:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ";" (1:12)
>
> 1 | mongodump --archive="mongo_signs1" --db=signs

Are there any alternatives, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

**For MongoDB 5.04 and MongoSH 1.1.2**

This process will back up your `signs` database and restore it to a `signs-backup` database on the same server.

Backup:

```
mongodump --archive="c:\dev\backup\mongodump-signs-db" --db=signs
```

Restore:

```
mongorestore --archive="c:\dev\backup\mongodump-signs-db" --nsFrom="signs.*" --nsTo="signs-backup.*"
```

Requirements:

1. Write permissions to the output directory (e.g. `c:\dev\backup`).
2. Double quotes around the `--nsFrom` and `--nsTo` values. The Mongo [docs example](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/#copy-clone-a-database) uses single quotes, and that failed for me.

**For previous Mongo and MongoSH versions**

See [Mongorestore to a different database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36321899).